# How is the best practices to build proxy server on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, squid

I added to my server IP Failover (32 IP / OVH). I want to build a proxy server on one container on docker on this server. Which tool/lib is the best in this situation?

I need a proxy for scraping several pages via puppeteer.
At the moment I using ten rows proxy, and I want similar links like ten rows for scraping:
curl -k "http://example.com" -L -x "http://67e5d6108f831a320d4e70e88e410a58518a9ade:@proxy.zenrows.com:8001"

I thinking about Squid, it is a good option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, squid-cache is a good option for forward-proxy.

You can use Ubuntu's docker image ubuntu/squid.

Regarding best practices:

- Set authentication or at least source-IP restrictions for your proxy
- Authenticate it over HTTPS. I faced a few challenges doing it a couple of years ago because most of the JavaScript libraries only supported proxy over HTTP, but, at the end of the day, it's achievable.